# Simplexml_load_file empty array

Tags: php, simplexml, wikipedia-api

I try to load this document:

```
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Electrophoresis&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500";
```

When I run it in browser, everything is fine.
When I do this:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'XX123456789 (localhost; myemailaddress)'); //sets info for authentication    
$content = file_get_content($url);
var_dump($content);
```

It return the same xml document as my browser show.

However when I try to

```
$content_arrays = Simplexml_load_file($content);
echo '<pre>', print_r($content_arrays), '</pre>';
```

It return a bunch of empty arrays. I just dont get why.

Comment: `$content` contains a string as returned by `file_get_contents()`.. Use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

Comment: I get the exact same result as when I used {simplexml_load_file}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) returns an object, not an array. So you can't just print it with print_r. You need to do more work to navigate through the SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: That's what I figured out afterward. Thanks